# Return multiple image files with Flask

Tags: python, flask

First I've searched a lot and didn't find a straight forward answer to my question yet.

I'm writing a new program which accepts an image and then find similar images to it and then extract image names from a database. I've created a simple response with the name of these image files as a JSON format with Flask in python3. I need to display these images with its name under it as a web page with a response in Flask. The major problem is the number of images are not fixed and may vary, sometimes it became as 10 and sometimes as 0. Actually, I'm not familiar with Flask or HTML, but I need to do it.
Here is my sample code which response the image names as an array:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, redirect, send_file
import numpy
import os
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_image():
    # Check if a valid image file was uploaded
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']

        if file.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            # The image file seems valid! Detect faces and return the result.
            return detect_faces_in_image(file)

    # If no valid image file was uploaded, show the file upload form:
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Face System</title>
    <h1>Upload a picture and see if it's a picture of database!</h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    '''


def detect_faces_in_image(file_stream):
    ...     #some coding to create the founded_file_names
    out=founded_file_names      #array of desired file names
    return jsonify(out)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First things first, *please* don't hardcode HTML into your python file. Make a `templates/` directory, and put all of this html into a file, lets say `homepage.html`. You can then use `return render_template('homepage.html')` to render the html.

---

Now, for the main question.

> The major problem is the number of images are not fixed and may vary, sometimes it became as 10 and sometimes as 0.

That won't be a problem if you use Jinja, which is included in flask. If you're not familiar with it, have a look at the [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/).

Looking at your code, the best way to do it would be the following: after the user submitted his image, you can show another page, lets say `results.html`(which you should put in `templates/`), and then show the pics there.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, redirect, send_file
import numpy
import os
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_image():
    # Check if a valid image file was uploaded
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return redirect(request.url)

        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            return redirect(request.url)

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            # The image file seems valid!
            # Get the filenames and pass the on to the results.html page
            return render_template(
                'results.html', results=detect_faces_in_image(file)
            )

    # If no valid image file was uploaded, show the file upload form:
    return render_template('homepage.html')


def detect_faces_in_image(file_stream):
    # .. do something here ...
    return file_names_found # list of the filenames, no need for JSON

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

Now, the front end. Here is a rough draft of what `results.html` could look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if results %}
        <table>
            <tbody>
            {% for img_name in results %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ img_name }}</td>
                    <td><img src="/pathtoyourimg" alt="{{ img_name }}"></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {% else %}
        No results :(
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

You can see that the Jinja syntax is very similar to python (if/else, for .. in ..). To use a variable, you must surround it with `{{ }}`. What HTML file does is:

- check whether `results if an empty list`

  - if it is, display 'no results :('
  - if it isn't, then display a html table. for each result, we make a row (`<tr>`) and display the name on the left, and the image on the right

You should store all of your images in a folder named `static/` next to the python script. If you do so, `src="/pathtoyourimg"` becomes `src="static/{{ img_name }}"`

Comment: @MasoudR. Absolute paths are usually not a very good idea. Why did you change the static path ? Which error did you get ?

Comment: @MasoudR. do you have your python file and the `static/` both in the same directory ? If you do, I made a typo in the answer, you should have `src="static/{{ img_name }}"` (without the / in front)

Comment: Thanks, I was misunderstanding your `static` folder. I created a `static` folder beside the python file and put my `test_images` folder in it and it worked. So if I want to put any data to load I should put it in `static` folder right?

Comment: @MasoudR. Sorry for being unclear, its exactly that. If you are using a web library like Flask, or Django, you will always have a `static/` directory where you put images, stylesheets (CSS) and also scripts (js).I clarified my answer.