# Flask for loop folder images

Tags: python, html, flask, server, web-development-server

I have some Flask code that is supposed to for loop thru a folder and return me the images from the folder to my website, but it does not work. It returns me an unavailable image HTML sign. In simpler terms, it is supposed to take all of the .png files from a folder and put them on my website. If there are other ways to do this please list tell me.
this is the code

```
import os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
  for filename in os.listdir():
      if filename.endswith(".png"):
        return f"<img src ={filename}>"


  
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

Comment: `listdir()` needs a path parameter, to tell it which directory to list the contents of. Try inserting a print statement to see what it is returning.

Comment: you need to use async code to send images in asynchronus manner, if you want to send images all at once,  i suggest you to first fetch all image and then send them as data

Comment: For async code should I use asyncio? How can I fetch all of the images at once? Thank you for the suggestions @sahasrara62

Comment: to get all image at once, write a seperate function, which when call upon will give you all image path,  on async one, you need to see how it work with the front end (as i am not into front end dev yet) apart from async you can do pagination and send images like that way too

Comment: Hmmm I see but the problem is that when you return in flask the function ends, I think, thank you for the answer now adding on your answer how can I return multiple images in one return function @sahasrara62

Comment: [Return multiple image files with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728047/return-multiple-image-files-with-flask/44734502)